# How to use xml type-valued functions in SQL Server FOR XML

Tags: sql-server, xml

Is there a way to make function work like an object?

e.g.: I have an xml typed function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CompanyXml(@id int) RETURNS XML 
AS 
BEGIN 
    RETURN (SELECT id AS [@id], name AS [@name] FROM Companies WHERE id = @id 
    FOR XML PATH('CompanyType'),TYPE)
END
```

When I use the function:

```
SELECT dbo.CompanyXml(1) AS Supplier,
    dbo.CompanyXml(2) AS Client
FOR XML PATH('Document'), TYPE
```

I get:

```
<Document>
  <Supplier>
    <CompanyType id="1" name="Company 1" />
  </Supplier>
  <Client>
    <CompanyType id="2" name="Company 2" />
  </Client>
</Document>
```

but i need:

```
<Document>
  <Supplier id="1" name="Company 1" />
  <Client id="2" name="Company 2" />
</Document>
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

**[UPDATE]  My solution**

(inspired by @Shnugo)

I have used table valued function with `FOR XML AUTO`

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CompanyTbl(@id int) RETURNS TABLE 
AS SELECT id, name FROM Companies WHERE id = @id
```

used like this

```
SELECT (SELECT * FROM dbo.CompanyTbl(1) AS Supplier FOR XML AUTO, TYPE),
       (SELECT * FROM dbo.CompanyTbl(2) AS Client FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
FOR XML PATH('Document'), TYPE
```

Comment: how first row is supplier and second row is client, what happens to 3rd row?

Comment: Other rows are Document Id, document Items (Goods) , Signing person etc. Excluded them to simplify the query.

Comment: Great solution! Just one hint: avoid *old-fashioned TVF*, rather use an *inline-TVF*. In your case this is very easy: `CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CompanyTbl(@id int) RETURNS TABLE AS SELECT id, name FROM Companies WHERE id = @id;`. This is **much better in performance**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alias `AS Supplier` or `AS Client` is the caption for a specific column in your result set. The function you are calling does not know (and can not know), that its result will be displayed as Supplier or as Client...

Further more the **element's name must be a literal** using `FOR XML PATH()`.

There are three approaches, I'd pick the last:

1. You can go with a modified function like Kannan Kandasamys' suggestion, but you will need one section per role and you must hand in the "type" as parameter. More roles will need modifications of the function. Might be difficult in deployed databases...
2. You could create the xml on string level (something like `'<' + @element + id="' + ...`) and then use a `CAST(... AS XML)`. Be careful how you deal with special characters in this case!
3. (My choice): Introduce one separate function for each document role. New roles are new functions, which is easier in most cases

For Nr 3 your code would look like

```
SELECT dbo.SupplierXml(1) AS [*],
       dbo.ClientXml(2) AS [*]
FOR XML PATH('Document'), TYPE;
```

### UPDATE One more approach: `FOR XML AUTO`

Try this:

```
CREATE DATABASE TestDB;
GO
USE TestDB;
GO
CREATE TABLE TestTable(id INT,SomeOther VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO TestTable VALUES(1,'Some 1'),(2,'Some 2');

SELECT * FROM TestTable FOR XML AUTO;
```

--The result: You see, that the table name is the element's name:

```
<TestTable id="1" SomeOther="Some 1" />
<TestTable id="2" SomeOther="Some 2" />
```

--Nice is, that you can force this name using a table alias:

```
SELECT * FROM TestTable AS OtherName FOR XML AUTO;
```

--returns

```
<OtherName id="1" SomeOther="Some 1" />
<OtherName id="2" SomeOther="Some 2" />

GO
USE master;
GO
DROP DATABASE TestDB;
```

Now the bad thing is, that - again - the alias must be a literal and cannot be passed in as parameter. It is not inlineable, but you might do something like

```
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(1000)='SELECT * FROM YourTable AS ' + @alias + ' FOR XML AUTO';
EXEC (@cmd);
```

When it comes to dynamically set column names (same applies to element names), you must use some ugly tricks...

Comment: I do use 1st approach now.
The bad thing is that I have 5 elements of the same "Company" type.
And the type has nearly 20 attributes/elements in it.

So I have to copy/paste 30 lines of code 5 times. 
And if I need to change somethig I will also have to repeat myself 5 times..

The best way could be using dynamic strings. But they don't work in functions.

Comment: It did the trick. Used table valued function with Alias. I didn't even use dynamic strings. (see updated topic)
Thanks a lot

Comment: I did try to upvote the answer at first but the system told me I need reputation 15+ to vote. So for now the only thing i can do is to say "thank you".

Comment: @Pasetchnik , no problem Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You can change the function as below:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CompanyXml1(@id int, @type varchar(15)) RETURNS XML 
AS 
BEGIN 
    if @type = 'Supplier' 
    begin
        return(
            SELECT id AS [@id], name AS [@name] FROM Companies WHERE id = @id 
            FOR XML PATH('Supplier'),TYPE )
    end
    else
    begin
        return(
                SELECT id AS [@id], name AS [@name] FROM Companies WHERE id = @id 
            FOR XML PATH('Client'),TYPE
            )
    end 
    return(null);       
END
```

your query as below:

```
SELECT dbo.CompanyXml1(1, 'Supplier'),
    dbo.CompanyXml1(2, 'Client') 
FOR XML PATH('Document'), TYPE
```

Output ...:

```
<Document>
  <Supplier id="1" name="Company 1" />
  <Client id="2" name="Company 2" />
</Document>
```

Comment: Thanks. I use this similar approach. But the real code is repeated 5 times and has 20 attributes instead of 2  :(
I dont like to repeating every change five times.